# How to translate labels in symfony forms generated with doctrine:crud

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

There Symfony project. He has `Entity/Record.php` With the command

`php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud --entity=AppBundle:Record`

Create a controller and a template. It seems to be nothing but one of the templates generated to create a new recording.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Create a form in the controller

```
$record = new Record();
$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\RecordType', $record);
```

Create a form in `Form/RecordType.php`

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('surname')
        ->add('patronymic')
        ->add('dOB', BirthdayType::class)
        ->add('phone')
    ;
  }
```

The form of work, all input fields are there, but the name in front of input fields, both logical and should have be generated - it attribute Entity object. But they are in English, which is inconvenient for the user (see. Screenshot). **How do I display them in Russian?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `RecordType` add

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'translation_domain' => 'forms'
        )
    );
}
```

and then create `forms.ru.yml` in `app/Resources/translations/` clear cache so new translation file is detected (important) and you can write translations by

```
# forms.ru.yml
Name: Имя
Surname: Фамилия
Phone: Телефон
```

**Above I assume your locale is set to `ru` if it's not then you will need to adjust file name.**